# Does any USAF fighter jet use surfaces near the front for pitch control?

Tags: military, flight-controls

Some European fighters like Eurofighter use frontal surfaces for pitch control. Does any US fighter use this configuration? And what are these surfaces called?

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canard_(aeronautics) - not used on production USAF fighter jets.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking of the Eurofighter Typhoon.

Comment: This is an "old continent thing". Typhoon, Rafale, JAS, and Sukhoi use this control method.

Answer (score 4):

These surfaces are called [**canards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canard_(aeronautics)).

To my knowledge no canard equipped fighter ever entered service with the armed forces, though there were a few experimental prototypes such as the CCV/AFTI F-16 or the F-15 ACTIVE which made use of canard foreplanes.

[image][image]

The Grumman X-29, Rockwell X-31, and Boeing X-36 are other examples of US technology demonstrators which made use of canards for extreme maneuvering, none of which were ever pursued further for development into a fighter aircraft.